# In App Purchase no valid Product IDs

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm trying to get In App Purchase with my existing iPad App working. I'm stuck retrieving the Product Information from App Store:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

The SKProductsResponse only contains invalid Product IDs. I tried every potential solution I found here or on the net:

- my App ID has In App enabled
- I generated a new provisioning profile and installed it on my device
- I restarted the device
- my App ID is the same as in my Info.plist (it's in the Store since weeks)
- I added In App Purchases for the App with "cleared for sale" checked
- I added Screenshots to my In App Purchases
- I tried different naming schemes for the Product ID
- I made triple checked that I pass the correct Product ID to the SKProductsRequest
- I'm passing a NSSet to the SKProductsRequest instead of a MutableSet
- I updated my App with the upcoming version containing in App purchase and submitted it for Review
- I approved one of my In App Purchases, just to see if that helps
- I waited more than 24 hours

All of these actions brought me nothing but invalid Product IDs.

I hope someone can point me into the right direction, because I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Sandbox, I guess. The question I ask myself is, what's the difference?

Comment: SOLUTION: There is no solution! It started working after a couple of days without me changing anything in my setup!

Comment: Is it possible that your 'Paid Applications' contract was incomplete or still in the "processing" state at the time when you were having this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Are you logged in as an In-App Purchase test user? (You can create one via iTunes Connect under manage users).   Products that have not been approved for sale will not appear if you're using a regular account, even if it's a development build, and even if the app itself has cleared for sale.  You may need to sign out of your regular account on the iPhone first (Home Screen -> Settings -> App Store -> Log out).

You say you're getting invalid product ids rather than none though - what kind of ids are you getting back? Are they gibberish or is it returning someone else's ids?  Examples would help.